# first iteration of sql query not being wrapped properly

Tags: php, css, sql

So, I've got this php file, but the first result isn't being wrapped in the 'result' div, and so isn't being styled properly.  All the subsequent results are being wrapped properly.  Help?

EDIT:
Per the comments, I've tried to pull the html out.  I admit I'm a noob, but here's what I've come up with for that.  Doesn't seem to fix the original issue:

**scripts_post.php:**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "password", "dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQuery);
mysqli_close($connection);
if (empty($result)) { 
    echo 'No results found'; 
    return;
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo include 'single_result.php';
    }
echo "<div class='results_end'><p>End of list</p></div>";
```

**single_result.php:**

```
    <div class='result'>
        <div class='result_left'>
            <div class='result_photo'><img src=<?php echo "'" . $row['PhotoLink'] . "'" ?> height='200' width='200' class='script_photo'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='results_right'>
            <div class='result_title'><?php echo $row['Title'] ?></div>
            <div class='result_summary'><?php echo $row['Summary'] ?></div>
            <div class='result_description'><?php echo $row['Description'] ?></div>
            <div class='result_preview'><a href =<?php echo "'" . $row['PreviewLink'] . "'" ?> target='_blank'>view preview</a></div>         
            <div class='result_detail'>Type: <?php echo $row['Type'] ?></div>   
            <div class='result_detail'>Biblical Characters Portrayed: <?php echo $row['BiblicalCharacters'] ?></div>
            <div class='result_detail'>Topics: <?php echo $row['Topics'] ?></div>
            <div class='result_price'>Cost: $<?php echo $row['Price'] ?></div>
            <div class='result_purchase'><a href =<?php echo "'" . $row['DownloadLink'] . "'" ?> target='_blank'><img src='http://image.payloadz.com/images/btn-addtocart-b.png' border='0'></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT #2: Here's what's calling the above.  Perhaps there's something here that's screwing with things?

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script language ="javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(event) {
                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize()
                }).done(function(returned_data) {
                    document.getElementById('scriptsearch_results_div').innerHTML = returned_data;
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("The search has failed.  Please alert the webmaster.");
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    ...
    <div id="formcontainer">
        <form id="scriptsearch_form" action="scripts_post.php" method="post">
            // form fields
            <p> <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submitbutton" id="mainsubmitbutton"> </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="scriptsearch_results_div">
        <p>Search for scripts using the options at left.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting all this HTML into your script in the first place. It's a recipe for pulling your hair out.

Comment: Fair.  What other options do I have?

Comment: use two files. One for the HTML, one for the script. Make the values from your script available to the other PHP file (containing your html) and just substitute values.

Comment: Just because i'am curious. What happens if you use an empty string as glue in the implode ?

Comment: You are right @elevenThousand_dB i was curious because there are differences between the english and German php docs. It sasy glue is optional in both cases. But in the German translation it says something like: "you should always define glue otherwise the wrong prototype could be used..."

Comment: Cool, @NicoO.  Wish it had helped.

Comment: @Zarathuztra, I've edited to comply with your suggestions.  First time, so go gently, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  Silly, really.  the `<body>` tag in scripts_post.php was actually `<body` and so the first `>` was closing the tag and the stuff between was being dumped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the 'result' div from the php loop. In other words, nest the php loop inside the 'result'div

Comment: The 'result' div is for each result, with styling to do divisions, etc:
.result {
    border-bottom: 1px lightgray solid;
    padding: 20px 0px; 
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 695px;
    overflow: auto;
}
The entire result set is wrapped in its own div.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert special characters in the texts that come from your database, becase they may break your HTML (I guess it is what happened in the first div)

Use [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

So, instead of:

```
<div class='result_summary'><?php echo $row['Summary'] ?></div>
```

it should be:

```
<div class='result_summary'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Summary']) ?></div>
```

The translations performed are:

- & (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`
- " (double quote) becomes `&quot;` when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- ' (single quote) becomes `&#039;` (or ') only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
- < (less than) becomes `&lt;`
- > (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

Comment: This wouldn't explain why the first iteration doesn't display correctly, yet all subsequent iterations do

Comment: Tried this with no expectations.  Nothing changed.